# PixelJunk Monsters - How to buy bombs from the shop?

Tags: pixeljunk-monsters

In PixelJunk Monsters, you can unlock Remote Mines after completing the level, Gati Gati Special 3, which cost 5 gems.

But I do not see the option for buying these remote mines in the store. You can see, every other unlocked upgrade here has a price and you can buy it (except the potion, which is always active).  Clicking the bomb icon (blue ball-like object with red on top), however, does nothing.  Yet clearly I have enough gems (11 here).

How do you buy Remote Mines from the store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The 5 gem is for dropping a remote mine; no need to buy them in advance.**

Deployed when S-button (square) is pressed on PS, then when the button is pressed again, it detonates.

Comment: Correct!  Did not see that at first, thank you!  Seems to be "D" key on my setup automatically: https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/958588338309324256/B82E37402541ECE8A1F8A7356C74F10CBD3100D7/